# what does this mean Inheritance Uses Computed Values

Tags: html, css

I'm reading [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa073007.htm)
and in chapter "Inheritance Uses Computed Values" they say the following:

> This is important for inherited values like font sizes that use
>   lengths. A computed value is a value that is relative to some other
>   value on the Web page.
>
> If you set a font-size of 1em on your BODY element, your entire page
>   will not be all only 1em in size. This is because elements like
>   headings (H1-H6) and other elements (some browsers compute table
>   properties differently) have a relative size in the Web browser. In
>   the absence of other font size information, the Web browser will
>   always make an H1 headline the largest text on the page, followed by
>   H2 and so on. When you set your BODY element to a specific font size,
>   then that is used as the "average" font size, and the headline
>   elements are computed from that.

So if you have set text size in the browser to normal that 1em is about the same as 16px.
If you know choose to set a greater text size in browser the text will be greater.

So I wonder what are they trying to say with the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically saying it's all relative, so let's say your body is 16px, unless you specify specifically everything will be computed from this value for other tags.

if you use em, then 1em will be 16px for the top elements.

Example:

```
<div class="monkeyAss">Hello
<h1>monkeyAss2</h1></div>

.monkeyAss {font-size: 0.5em;}
.monkeyAss h1 {font-size: 1em}
```

Here your monkeyAss will be as expected 8px, for 1em, but then since h1 is inside another parent div, it's going to be also 8px, taking its value from its relative parent.  hope that helps.

Comment: Assume use have 1em in the body which is 16px in most browsers if you have the brower in normal text size. If then monkeyAss is 0.5em you have 8px because body was 16px and 16px *0.5 = 8px further we have the inner h1 with the text monkeyAss2 will also be 8px from the parent. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

It means, that when you set `font-size` on element it's real value is related to values set in parent elements.

Example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ajE25/)

```
<div id="test1">
    <h1>First header</h1>
</div>
<div id="test2">
    <h1>Second header</h1>
</div>
```

```
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }

#test1 { font-size: 1em; }
#test2 { font-size: 2em; }
```

`font-size: 1.5em` on `h1` element is calculated relatively to it's parent and the second heading is bigger.

Comment: This is how I understand it. If I just add an h1 before the first div it will have font size 1.5em which is about 24px 1em is normally 16px. The first heder that is defined as 1em will be based on the default font-size that is 1.5em from the parent. So this first heder will be 1.5em or about 24px. The second header that is defined as 2em is also based on the parent 1.5em that is the defualt font-size or about 24px so 2em will be something like 48px.